# RewriteRule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^upload$ upload.php
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)/?.*$ /view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The first rule successfully works. When I navigate to `http://localhost/upload` it shows the upload.php page.

The second rule however, does not. When I browse to: `http://localhost/1234/some-string` I get a 404 error. It's meant to show this page: `http://localhost/view.php?id=1234`.

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do with the rule, I want the last string on the end of the URL to be completely ignored, and take the `1234` as a parameter for view.php.

Can anyone spot why this isn't working? I've tried everything I can think of, but to no success. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be trying to find the directory `/1234/` and failing. change the `/` to a `-` and it should work

EDIT: got that completely wrong ... it's actually that you have a `/` at the beginning of your pattern, whereas MOD_REWRITE receives the path without the first slash.

Comment: Edit: sorry, got it wrong. You're right. It works if I do this instead: `RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?.*$ /view.php?id=$1 [L]`. Not sure what you meant by the `-`, though.

Comment: it is because it looks for directories first, I dont know how to stop it doing that. The first works because the url does not end with a `/` (nor would it work in that case, because the rule doesn't specify that eventuality.